# Adding properties to a existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery

thsi is not a jquery ui question but a JavaScript object question

```
function uiDialog()
{    
   ...............
   ...............

    $('#dialog ').dialog({
        width:'auto',
        height :'auto',
        resizable: false 
    });
    ..............
    ..............
}
```

Above is a jquery ui dialog code. Now everywhere i want a dialog am calling uiDialog(). Now ui has so many options that are rarely required. So i am considering passing a object as a parameter and appending it to this default data   but how can i do it .can i do

```
$('#dialog ').dialog({
    width:'auto',
    height :'auto',
    resizable: false,
    myObject 
});
```

Will this work or can you suggest any other way if this fails

Comment: jqueryUI you mean right? If YES - then in the most basic 'default' way to call it you can do something like: $(foo).dialog();

Comment: yes and that's precisely what i am doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`jQuery.extend();` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend).

```
$('#dialog ').dialog(
  $.extend(
    {
      width:'auto',
      height :'auto',
      resizable: false
    },
    myObject 
  )
);
```